# Android ListActivity doesn't center the items

Tags: android-layout, listview, adapter, listadapter, layout-gravity

I have a ListActivity which displays an image and some text.
The imageView has a fixed size and I want to center the list horizontally.
After endless tries, I set any gravity to center_horinzontal, but nothing works.

The list is shown over the whole screen, as I can see by the scrollbar on the right side. But my frame remains on the left side.
In the adapter class, which entends ArrayAdapter, I even tried to set the gravity during runtime, but when I try to  manipulate then basic LinearLayout, I get the error:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams"
```

My attempt to change gravity in the method getView() which throws the error:

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bootsFrameLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The list row is designed in a layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bootsFrameLayout"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/card_blank2"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bootsName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/BootNameStyle" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bootImage"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test_boot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textWatchList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/gray_transparent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/watchlist"
        android:textAppearance="@style/BootWatchListStyle" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/bootProgressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bootMasse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BootInfoStyle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bootBaujahr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BootInfoStyle" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bootLand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BootInfoStyle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bootPreis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BootPreisStyle" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The ListView is defined here:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="8" >
</ListView>
```

The activity occupies the whole screen, as it should do.
But although there is place enough, the frame won't center.

Any ideas?